# Javascript nested enum with numerical values

Tags: typescript, enums

Currently the enum has this shape which works fine:

```
export enum CountryIndex {
  JAPAN = 0,
  CHINA = 1,
  INDIA = 2 
}
```

I need to add a category inside of it, for example continents, in order to look like this:

```
export enum CountryIndex {
  ASIA: { JAPAN = 0,
          CHINA = 1,
          INDIA = 2
        },
  EUROPE: { SPAIN = 0,
            ITALY = 1
          }
}
```

The above one is not correct, is there a way to make a nested enum with numerical values?

Comment: See: [Objects vs Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying types for an enum values need to be either strings or numbers.

Your closest thing would be to use objects. Something similar to this

```
export const CountryIndex = {
  ASIA: {
    JAPAN: 0,
    CHINA: 1,
    INDIA: 2,
  },
  EUROPE: {
    SPAIN: 0,
    ITALY: 1 
 }
} as const
```